# MySQL: delete rows with "WHERE ... NOT IN" from only one single table

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL database I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables. For the sake of simplicity let's assume those tables map `homes` and their `residents`. I have a third table to map those relations (`home_resident_relations`). The latter table has an additional column `datemodified` that stores the date of the latest update of each row via triggers.

Now I want to get rid of all former residents for each home and only keep the current ones - that is those with the newest date.
I have already a working SELECT clause that will list me all old relations I want to delete:

```
SELECT * FROM `home_resident_relations` WHERE `resident_id` NOT IN 
    (SELECT tbl.`resident_id`   
    FROM `home_resident_relations` tbl
    WHERE tbl.`datemodified` = 
        (SELECT max(tbl2.`datemodified`) 
        FROM `home_resident_relations` tbl2 
        WHERE tbl2.`home` = tbl.`home` 
        GROUP BY tbl2.`home`)
    OR tbl.`datemodified` IS NULL
);
```

Now it would be a straight-forward idea to simply replace the `SELECT *` with a `DELETE` command to remove all those rows. However, this does not work due to error

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'home_resident_relations' for update in FROM clause
```

So here's my question:

**How do I delete from a table while using it in the WHERE ... NOT IN clause?**

Comment: `NOT IN` is tricky when it comes to NULL. Do `NOT EXISTS` instead. Don't do = sub-query that can return more than 1 row.

Comment: Your error suggests that your real query is an `update` query, yet the one you show starts with a `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff as written in the text, this error occurs while replacing the SELECT with a DELETE command - which is, by definition, a table update.

Comment: @jarlh I tried using `NOT EXISTS` without success (i.e. it doesn't even list me the desired rows anymore). Can you post an example, please?

Comment: See below :-) I'm just trying to be correct, not unfair...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join` instead:

```
DELETE hrr
    FROM `home_resident_relations` hrr LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT tbl.`resident_id`   
          FROM `home_resident_relations` tbl
          WHERE tbl.`datemodified` = (SELECT max(tbl2.`datemodified`) 
                                      FROM `home_resident_relations` tbl2 
                                      WHERE tbl2.`home` = tbl.`home` 
                                      GROUP BY tbl2.`home`
                                     ) OR
               tbl.`datemodified` IS NULL
         ) tt
         ON hrd.resident_id = tt.resident_id
    WHERE tt.resident_id IS NULL;
```

This works for both the `SELECT` and `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DELETE with join:

```
DELETE FROM `home_resident_relations`
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               (SELECT tbl.`resident_id`   
                FROM `home_resident_relations` tbl
                WHERE tbl.`datemodified` = 
                                          (SELECT max(tbl2.`datemodified`) 
                                           FROM `home_resident_relations` tbl2 
                                            WHERE tbl2.`home` = tbl.`home` )
                OR tbl.`datemodified` IS NULL) s
 ON(s.`resident_id` = `home_resident_relations`.`resident_id`)
WHERE s.`resident_id` is null
```

Comment: You can remove the GROUP BY from the inner sub-query.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Though you were a little faster than @GordonLinoff with almost the same code, there is a little mistake: without the "hrr" in `DELETE hrr FROM ...` as in his post, I get an SQL Syntax error.
If I am wrong on this, I'll change the accepted answer :-)